# URLEncode characters in string for a curl request using bash?

Tags: bash, api, shell, curl, urlencode

I am working on a wit.ai project and I want the user to be able to type a query/request in plain human readable text (e.g "Turn on the lights") and the program will convert it to a formatted version designed to be put in a `curl` request (e.g "Turn%20on%20the%20lights").

How would I for example turn "Stack Exchange" into "Stack%20Exchange" using tools in bash?

Answer (score 3):

Not really a basic shell tool but I've used `jq` for the job:

```
$ echo -n "Stack exchange" | jq -sRr @uri
Stack%20exchange%0A
```

To get rid of the `%0A` use `echo -n`, naturally.

Comment: `echo -n` is non-standard, so this instead: `printf 'Stack exchange' | jq -sRr @uri`. Or even better: `jq -nRr --arg s 'Stack exchange' '$s|@uri'` saving an unnecessary sub-shell.

Comment: how can we decode this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
read -e a # read from the keyboard interactively into the variable `a`
sed 's/ /%20/g' <<<$a # replace spaces to "$20" in `a` with the command `sed` and print it
```

or

```
echo $a |sed 's/ /%20/g'
```

If you want to put it into a variable:

```
b=$(sed 's/ /%20/g' <<<$a)
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works? And what variables I would replace with my own